# How to tell if VLC is playing anything or not with AutoHotKey?

Tags: vlc-media-player, autohotkey

Is there a way in AutoHotkey to find out if VLC is playing anything or not?

My purpose is to only send Full Screen key <kbd>F</kbd> and Aspect Ratio key <kbd>A</kbd> if VLC is playing something; if not, wait for it to play something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to tell if VLC is playing anything or not is to check its window title like so:

```
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

SetTimer, checkVLC, 5000
Return

checkVLC:
    IfWinExist, VLC media player
    {
        WinGetTitle, VLCTitle, VLC media player 
        if (strlen(VLCTitle) > 16)
        {
            ; Perform your keypresses here. I am showing the currently playing media
            StringReplace, NowPlaying, VLCTitle,  - VLC media player, , 
            msgbox % NowPlaying
        }
    }
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), since it seems all you want to do is view every video in fullscreen and with a specific aspect ratio. If so, why don't you change the default options under `Tools / Preferences / Video`?

[image: 1]