# How can I set the default aspect ratio for videos in VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player, default-settings, video-playback, aspect-ratio

When opening video files, sometimes the aspect ratio doesn't fit my TV and I see black bars either side:

> [image]

How can I set the default aspect ratio to 16:9, so that I don't have to right-click and change each video's aspect ratio manually every time?

Comment: I discussed this just a few weeks back [here](http://superuser.com/a/607897/138343), but the question title would probably not make it show up while searching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open VLC, and go to *Tools > Preferences*.

1. Choose *Show settings > All*.
2. From the left pane, scroll down to the bottom and click *Video*.
3. From the right pane, scroll down to *Source aspect ratio*; fill in `16:9`.
4. Hit <kbd>Save</kbd>:

[image]

The next time you open VLC, your videos will automatically have your chosen aspect ratio:

> [image]